# Run another python file while executing current file code simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, subprocess, os.system

I have two files, start.py and test.py. My test.py is having tkinter codes.

So, when I execute my start.py:

```
print("Hi")
os.system('python test.py')
print("Hello")
```

It will print Hi and then will run test.py

Hello will only be printed when I close that tkinter window. (meaning test.py completed its full code)

But I need test.py to be opened differently, and my start.py should execute further simultaneously (it should not matter, if I have closed the tkinter or not, it should mover ahead)

I also tried it:- `subprocess.call(['python', 'test.py'])`

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen()` instead.

Comment: Use `import test` but do it in another thread

Comment: Just use threading.